# Resources in a separate assembly not visible in different build configurations

Tags: c#, resources, .net-assembly, resx, buildconfiguration

I have a problem with resources with localizations in web application. I need to use them from different assemblies (WebSite, BLL, etc.) so I decided to move them to a separate library.
I'm using three different build configurations (Debug, Release and QA which is based on Release). When I run the application locally everything is fine (independently from configuration). The problem is when I deploy it on IIS (same situation for local or external server). Deployment in Debug configuration works fine but in QA or Release I get this exception:

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any
>   resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral
>   culture.  Make sure "MyToolResources.Resources.Emails.Mail.resources"
>   was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "BusinessLogicLayer" at
>   compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are
>   loadable and fully signed.

I found many topics with that problem but none of them was depending on build / deployment configuration.

Assemblies:
MyTool - web site
BusinessLogicLayer - class library
MyToolResources - class library with resources

My resource manager:

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
mailResourceManager = new ResourceManager("MyToolResources.Resources.Emails.Mail", assembly);

private static ResourceSet GetResourceSet(ResourceManager resourceManager, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return resourceManager.GetResourceSet(culture, true, true);
}
```

The assembly with resources is correctly copied into /bin directory - same in Debug and QA/Release configurations.

Comment: I have deployed the same version on my local IIS and on external server. Locally I get exception and on external IIS it finds resources correctly. Can anyone tell me which IIS property may have influence on that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing both IIS configurations I have finally found the solution. Build for deployment has to be **explicitly targeted to x86** (even for x64 environment) and then it works.